# Can't get value from JTOken

Tags: c#, json

I have this JToken

```
var pv = JToken.Parse(keys["parameterValues"].ToString()).ToList()[0];
```

Which returns this value

```
{"DE:Actual Savings": 42217.0}
```

I can't use .Value because the float is represented as an object `{42217.0}`

How can I get this number? Right now I am using .ToString() and converting it

Comment: `float val = float.Parse(YourObj.Value)`;

Comment: I can't use .Value I tried .Value<float>() but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the value to a defined type you could use one of the defined methods below:

```
System.Convert.ChangeType(jtoken.ToString(), targetType);
```

or

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jtoken.ToString(), targetType);
```

Let's take into consideration our sample:

```
string json = @{"DE:Actual Savings": 42217.0}
```

You could do something like:

```
var obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Type type = typeof(float);
var i1 = System.Convert.ChangeType(obj["DE:Actual Savings"].ToString(), type);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I have never dealt with JSON in .net but the value's I am getting are horribly formatted. Thanks for this answer it works! That's exactly what I was doing without the `ChangeType()` What is the difference in using TryParse on the tostring?